# Ultrasonic transducer for NDT short circuit

Tags: impedance, ultrasound, transducer

i have bought several transducer for NDT test from some manufacturers, but before i tried them, i checked that the impedance between the positive and negative transducer just around 2 Ohm, and it didn't work with this circuit

[image]

is it normal? because i have an old transducer worked properly and has around 3 MegaOhm impedance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist multiple types of ultrasound transducers: **Piezoelectric types** need an AC voltage and they have high resistance. **Magnetic types** need an AC current and they have low resistance.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, so it won't work with my pulser schematic right? I have tried to find pulser schematic for the magnetic transducer but i cannot find it

Comment: Put your transducer between R2 and M1 in your schematic and change R2 value to maybe 100 Ohms.